# What is the working logic of '==' while comparing two objects?

Tags: java

What logic works when we compare two objects using '==' ? This logic is written in which file ? FYI I am aware that JVM checks if both reference variable point to the same object; I want to know what code must be there to determine if both reference point to same object ?

Comment: `MyObj obj1 = new MyObj(); MyObj obj2 = obj1;` now  `obj1==obj2` is true

Comment: [JavaWorld's Explanation](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072762/java-app-dev/object-equality.html)

Comment: [Oracle's Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: I'm curious what real-world problem you're trying to solve. SO isn't really for theoretical questions, see [the help](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Its more of a conceptual one.There must be a code to describing logic of '=='.I am Curious to see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately this comes down to the Java virtual instruction set instructions [`if_acmpeq` and `if_acmpne`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_acmp_cond), described jointly as `if_acmp<cond>`:

> **Operation**
>
> Branch if reference comparison succeeds
>
> **Format**
>
> ```
> if_acmp
> branchbyte1
> branchbyte2
> ```
>
> **Forms**
>
> - `if_acmpeq` = 165 (0xa5)
> - `if_acmpne` = 166 (0xa6)
>
> **Operand Stack**
>
> ```
> ..., value1, value2 →
> ...
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Both `value1` and `value2` must be of type reference. They are both popped from the operand stack and compared. The results of the comparison are as follows:
>
> - `if_acmpeq` succeeds if and only if `value1` = `value2`
> - `if_acmpne` succeeds if and only if `value1` ≠ `value2`
>
> If the comparison succeeds, the unsigned `branchbyte1` and `branchbyte2` are used to construct a signed 16-bit offset, where the offset is calculated to be `(branchbyte1 << 8) | branchbyte2`. Execution then proceeds at that offset from the address of the opcode of this `if_acmp<cond>` instruction. The target address must be that of an opcode of an instruction within the method that contains this `if_acmp<cond>` instruction.
>
> Otherwise, if the comparison fails, execution proceeds at the address of the instruction following this `if_acmp<cond>` instruction.

Which begs the question of what it means by the values being equal. I think that's left up to the JVM implementation. Here's [what the spec has to say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.2) about values of type `reference`:

> The Java Virtual Machine contains explicit support for objects. An object is either a dynamically allocated class instance or an array. A reference to an object is considered to have Java Virtual Machine type `reference`. Values of type `reference` can be thought of as pointers to objects. More than one reference to an object may exist. Objects are always operated on, passed, and tested via values of type reference.

And [further down](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4):

> There are three kinds of `reference` types: class types, array types, and interface types. Their values are references to dynamically created class instances, arrays, or class instances or arrays that implement interfaces, respectively.
>
> An array type consists of... *(largely irrelevant here)*
>
> A `reference` value may also be the special `null` reference, a reference to no object, which will be denoted here by `null`. The `null` reference initially has no run-time type, but may be cast to any type. The default value of a `reference` type is `null`.
>
> The Java Virtual Machine specification does not mandate a concrete value encoding `null`.

If the JVM spec doesn't specify the bits that define `null`, I'm thinking it doesn't specify the bits of a reference at all. Which makes sense. At that point, you're near the metal, which is the job of a specific JVM implementation. If you want to know the specifics at that level, at least one JVM is [open source](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/).

Answer (score 1):

The logic is written in the JVM's source code, essentially comparing pointers.

For example the `if_acmpeq` bytecode performs a branch (jump) if references are equal.

Comment: Isn't that one written in C, which would make a `==` translate right down to processor instructions, which would in turn mean that the "logic" is somewhere in Intel's/AMD's/ARM's/... CPU schematics?

Comment: Well everything translates eventually to processor instructions. From Java source to bytecode, then bytecode is interpreted or compiled to native code.

Comment: True, but it isn't really Java's doing if the underlying architecture supports it, and Java can just pass it down. Like, Java relies on the `==` operator to define the `==` operator...

Comment: Java defines the java bytecode, which is guaranteed to have the `if_acmpeq` instruction. You could create a JVM that would interpret all the bytecode, and it would be able to run even if the computer architecture didn't have that kind of instructions.